# I don't Understand - *(uint*)((byte*)p + Offset)

Tags: hex, byte, uint

I am having trouble understanding this code and would like a good explanation.

The following function takes in a hex file and modifies the address without overwriting everything else.

Can someone explain to me how its doing that?

```
unsafe void WriteUint32(void* p, int Offset, uint value)
        {
            *(uint*)((byte*)p + Offset) = value;
        }
```

Comment: What about it *do* you understand?

Comment: *(uint*)((byte*)p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we ignore `Offset`, you have

```
*(uint*)((byte*)p) = value;
```

which is just assigning `value` to what `p` points to, interpreted as a `uint`.

Adding `Offset` just changes the pointer to where `value` is being assigned.